# Wildfly server doesn't work, errors WFLYCTL0412 & WFLYCTL0180

Tags: java, xml, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to add a mysql datasource to my wildfly 26 server and when I deploy it I encounter the following error:

I saved a copy of my standalone and tried to redo it, since I've heard the xml can be quite tricky, however that didn't change anything. Also looked for blankspaces in the beginning of each xml document as per another stackoverflow post - but no bueno.

```
13:07:14,521 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "ISProjectEAR.ear")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.jdbc.dsLabs"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"ISProjectEAR.ear/ISEJBProject.jar#LabEJBSql\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.jdbc.dsLabs]",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"ISProjectEAR.ear/ISEJBProject.jar#LabEJBSql\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.jdbc.dsLabs]"
    ]
}
13:07:14,675 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "ISProjectEAR.ear" (runtime-name : "ISProjectEAR.ear")
13:07:14,727 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.jdbc.dsLabs (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."ISProjectEAR.ear/ISEJBProject.jar#LabEJBSql", service jboss.persistenceunit."ISProjectEAR.ear/ISEJBProject.jar#LabEJBSql".__FIRST_PHASE__] 
WFLYCTL0448: 33 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed
13:07:14,864 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
13:07:14,873 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 26.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 18.0.0.Final) started (with errors) in 16170ms - Started 607 of 832 services (43 services failed or missing dependencies, 347 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
13:07:14,878 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
13:07:14,879 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
```

Here's my module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="sqljdbc4.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

This is the datasource from my standalone.xml

```
<datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/dsLabs" pool-name="MysqlDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false" statistics-enabled="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433; databaseName=T4Lab;</connection-url>
                    <driver>sqljdbc4</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>Din anvandare</user-name>
                        <password>Ditt password</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                        <background-validation-millis>1</background-validation-millis>
                    </validation>
                    <statement>
                        <prepared-statement-cache-size>0</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="sqljdbc4" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
```

Here's the persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="LabEJBSql">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/dsLabs</jta-data-source>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/dsLabs</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs to see if the datasource has been deployed, or if there has been a problem preventing the datasource from deploying?

Comment: @SJuan76 Just checked to service.logs and found several errors, mostly ones which says "address already in use bind /127.0.0.1:9990". Tried to increment the port by one but didn't make any difference. You got any ideas? thanks